# setGravity method is no-op - when called on text toasts

Tags: android, android-toast, android-11

In the [official android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)), it is mentioned that the `setGravity` method on toasts will be  no-ops, when called on text toasts - with apps targeting Android `Build.VERSION_CODES#R`,

My own understanding from above is the text toasts with `setGravity` set on it for apps with target API  `Build.VERSION_CODES#R` will simply be not respecting the Gravity configuration set using
`setGravity` method.

If this understanding holds true - are there any alternatives to adjust the gravity of text toast with apps targeting `Build.VERSION_CODES#R` ?

Also, what are the possible reasons to impose such a restriction on text toast - from design point of view?

Comment: Did you find answer for this?